# How can I connect GSP Template Engines in a Controller with my Domain in Grails?

Tags: grails, controller, template-engine

I did [this tutorial](http://mrhaki.blogspot.co.uk/2010/05/grails-goodness-use-gsp-template-engine.html) to use the GSP Template Engine in a Controller to generate a view. Now I want to access to my database inside the html that I have in my controller, but I don't find the good way to do it. I want to access to my column name and template that I have in my domain.

I need to do it of this way, I know that I can do the same with the gsp file.

Controller:

```
class SendEmailController {
def groovyPagesTemplateEngine

def emailTemplate = {   
    def templateText = '''\

    <html>
        <body>
            <h1 align="center">Hello</h1>
                <p align="center">This is my text</p>
        </body>
    </html>
            '''
    def output = new StringWriter() 
    groovyPagesTemplateEngine.createTemplate(templateText, 'sample').make([show: true]).writeTo(output)
    render output.toString()
}   
}
```

DOMAIN

```
class SendEmail {
    String name
    String template


    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

Comment: So you pretty much want to replace the bit `createTemplate(templateText, 'sample')` with `createTemplate(SendEmail.get(0).template, SendEmail.get(0).name)`, right? or you want to store the rendered result? Or you want to include the content of the SendEmail.template and render it as part of the overall template defined in your controller?

Comment: I want to include the content of the SendEmail.name and SendEmail.template and render

Comment: Another question, that I have curiosity, if I replace that you tell me, How can I include the data that I have store in the domain in the Template??

Comment: As I see it, you simply add to your template something like `<div>${show}</div>` or if you pass in a SendEmail instance under say `sendEmail` then `<div>${sendEmail.template}</div>`. It gets more complicated when the template itself should be processed too.

Comment: Excuse me, but I'm really new in grails... I have to put this to access to my data: def templateText = '''\
  
  <html>
   <body>
<h1 align="center">Hello <div>${SendEmail.name}</div></h1>
     <p align="center"><div>${SendEmail.template}</div></p>
   </body>
  </html>
    '''
  def output = new StringWriter() 
  groovyPagesTemplateEngine.createTemplate(SendEmail.get(0).template, SendEmail.get(0).name).make([show: true]).writeTo(output)
  render output.toString()

Comment: If I put this, after to store in the database a name and a template, I get this error: Message Cannot get property 'template' on null object

Comment: I see, the problem is that you have to provide the SendEmail instance. The best way to do so is to add it to the model `....make([show: true, SendEmail:SendEmail.get(your id)]).write....`

Comment: I've modified that you tol me. This is my code: def templateText = '''\
  
  <html>
   <body>
    <h1 align="center">Hello <div>${SendEmail.name}</div></h1>
     <p align="center">This is text</p>
   </body>
  </html>
    '''
  def output = new StringWriter() 
  groovyPagesTemplateEngine.createTemplate(SendEmail.get(0).template, SendEmail.get(0).name).make([show: true, SendEmail:SendEmail.get(0)]).writeTo(output)
  render output.toString()
 } And I have this error: Message
Cannot get property 'template' on null object

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78903/discussion-between-defectus-and-salva).

Comment: This is the solution that work ok: def emailTemplate = {

def templateText = '''\

<html>
<body>
<h1>Hello ${SendEmail.name}</h1>
<p>This is the template ${SendEmail.template}</p>
</body>
</html>
'''
def output = new StringWriter()
groovyPagesTemplateEngine.createTemplate(templateText, SendEmail.get(params.id).name).make([show: true, SendEmail:SendEmail.get(params.id)]).writeTo(output)
render output.toString()
}

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve a domain object in your controller by calling get() (passing in the id of the record you want to retrieve from the database) on the domain object class.

```
def emailTemplate = SendEmail.get(id).template
```

There are some other retrieval methods as well.  Look at the GORM documentation for more information: https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/GORM.html.